# Extraer datos api twitter

Tags: javascript, html

Alguien sabe como extraer datos de la api de twitter y pintarlos en pantalla? ya vi la documentación pero en verdad no se como hacerlo.

Mi código:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>twitter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codebird.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

</head>
<body>
    

<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="content-text"></div>

    
        

    <script>
    var cb = new Codebird;
    cb.setConsumerKey('55AtROcvPkhlQhBPbpAIywBxb','4XVEJkgugMKsfysLjDqOOtiX0sXO69zjdLvZaGVJJtejacDCyo');
    cb.setToken('1045064296714162176-ATsuycQD3wFFVzenW4x5UYGO0jjNSC','ZiVviLcWUEvpXG2lPIZlFv9fEtEgzpPXOv0Evb9ck9Hbf');

        var params = { 
  q :  "sttmed" 
}; cb . __call ( "search_tweets" , params, function ( reply ) {
   // ... 
   console.log(reply)
});

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yo uso la libreria **[Codebird](https://www.jublo.net/projects/codebird/js)**, es bastante completa y me funcionó bien.

Una vez q tengas la libreria, se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
//esto hace la conexion
var cb = new Codebird;
cb.setConsumerKey("YOURKEY", "YOURKEY");
var params = {
  q: "tag-a-buscar",
  lang:'es'
};
// params puede no tener ningun parametro, es opcional
var twitts;

cb.__call(
  "search_tweets",
  params,
  function(reply) {
    // aca salen los tweets
    twitts = reply;
  },
  true // this parameter required
);
```

Comment: Te dejo un [link de un repo](https://github.com/leomagari-os/pagina_tp4/blob/master/js/codebird.js) que tiene el archivo _codebird.js_ por si no lo encuentras.

Comment: Ya instale Codebird y me sale undefined cuando busco los tweets.

Comment: Donde te marca el error? asignaste las keys correspondientes? Intenta utilizando el activo de codebird que te deje en los comentarios.

Comment: Solo con eso funcionaria ?

Comment: No tengo manera de saberlo sin ver como lo tienes implementado. A mi me funciona asi. Desde el HTML incluye primero el archivo de la librería codebird, y luego el activo con la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: Amigo, ya me funciono de esta manera, pero como los puedo pintar en pantalla? ya lo tengo en la consola, ya pongo el código arriba.

Comment: Eso ya no es parte de la pregunta, pero **para probar**, podes hacer un div e insertarle los datos con un **[innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)**.